# How to add specific features to CRF POS Tagger in Python?

Tags: python, function, language-features, pos-tagger, crf

I am using CRF POS Tagger in Python, training English PTB sample corpus and the result is quite good.

Now I want to use CRF to train on a large Vietnamese corpus. I need to add some Vietnamese features into this tagger like proper name, date-time, number,... I tried for days but cannot figure out how to do that. I already knew the format of data so it is not problem.

I am quite new to Python. So any detailed answer can be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend use CRF tagger, it's very easy.

Comment: please share an example.